# Why does instantiating COM object in C# throw exception

Tags: c#, c++, com, windows-10

I'm trying to instantiate a COM object, defined in a x86 dll written in Borland C++, in a testing program i write in C# (.net 4.7.2). The COM dll (server) is working, I have a windows service also written in C++ Borland that can use it and instantiate a COM object from the class (using CoCreateInstance). The dll is registered and the InprocServer32 entry has the correct path to the dll. There is no coclass existing in a typelib, only interfaces (those exist in the typelib). I have used the TlbImp to create dll:s which i reference in the c# project. In the project the target platform is set to x86. The way i try to instantiate an object is:

```
var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ins.MyComType");
object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

however the second line gives me

> "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll"
>   with the message 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID {C4363C5E-3831-46DF-8701-60C8D1B612BA} failed due to the
>   following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).".

It does not matter if i try to run the app as administrator. I have a vague memory of trying out a similar thing a couple of years ago and that it at that time worked. It was probably on a Win 7 machine (might even have been a 32-bit system). I have tried to open the project in DependencyWalker but i'm not sure what i'm looking at. I get a couple of errors:

> *Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>   *Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
>   *Error: A circular dependency was detected.
>   *Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
>   *Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Does any one have any idea on what it could be causing the exception? Or if i could get some hints as of how to dig deeper into dependencywalker? I get a gigantic tree of systemassembly stuff but i cannot see any obvious assembly standing out, though DW refers to many of them as being 64 bit. My guess is some dependent dll(s) somewhere should be x86 but which one(s). Is there a redist similar thingi i should have installed for this to work?

best regards

/Erik

Comment: Search the registry for `C4363C5E-3831-46DF-8701-60C8D1B612BA` and that should lead you to the problem dll.

Comment: You can easily write a 10 line C++ program that instantiates the object using COM. If the object implements IDispatch, then you should write a vbscript that instantiates the object using the 32-bit version of cscript/wscript (in c:\windows\syswow64 ). I'm just trying to strip out the .NET stuff first since you say it is written in a native language. Then, use procmon to see what modules are trying to be loaded and why it fails. procmon shows you the registry entries the program looks for and also what files it accesses and what modules it tries to load.

Comment: @RamblinRose, as i tried to inform I already have an app written in native C++ that can instantiate COM object from the COM class using prog id to get the clsid and then CoCreateInstance. In that app everything works fine. Not sure though if you were refering to something else?

Comment: @Joseph Willcoxson (please see also my previous comment). Dont know much about vbscript but will try and look into it. Since i have a native c++ app that can instantiate the COM class my main concern is why the .NET layer is (probably) causing problems. Does vbscript have any relation to .NET? Could it be conveived as somewhere between native and .NET? Is there any purpose to make a vbscript when i have the native app working properly already? Will also have a look at procmon, thanks!

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find out what DLL it is looking for.   Could be the Borland C++ runtime library for example.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thanks for the reply. Yep it was a missing dll. My own "helper" dll. With my working native app it is installed/provided automagically. But now in my new .net test app i have to make sure to manually (currently) provide the dll. Had forgotten all about it and had my sight narrowly set to some missing windows system dll (have had that problem before).

Comment: So the marked answer was not actually the solution.  Be sure to tell us what you did to diagnose and solve this in your own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a simple VBScript that contains these lines:

```
set obj = CreateObject("ins.MyComType")
MsgBox TypeName(obj)
```

Name the file test.vbs

Execute the command:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe test.vbs
```

Using the version from syswow64 ensures that it uses the 32-bit version of wscript.exe which can instantiate 32-bit COM objects. The version in c:\windows\system32 can only instantiate 64-bit In-process COM objects in DLLs...you said your object is a 32-bit COM DLL server.

If the vbscript fails, it could be that the object is not automation compatible--implements IDispatch. Otherwise you will get an error message why it fails.

If it succeeds,  you will know there is probably nothing on the C++ side causing problems. You THINK this is the case...but where is the runtime for Borland C++? Is everything statically linked, or is some of it dynamically linked? If it is dynamically linked, where is it in the path? It could be that the C++ service you have has the library in its path so that when it loads your COM object, the library is available. But, when you try to load from a 3rd party, like .NET or VBScript then the path to the library manifests itself.  Who knows? I'm just making suggestions.

If you use ProcMon, it can see where the problems are. It will show you what registry entries are being read and which files are trying to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Started out the path with the script and started looking into using ProcMon. However, all (most of you who in any way answered/commented this question) your "nagging" about missing dll finally got me thinking it could be something else than some obscure win x86 system dll missing, which i took for granted was the problem starting out (i know, not good...). And at that point i remembered the "helper" dll used by my COM dll. Once i copied that to the right place it started working properly. Thanks!